# What is this jugendstil / art nouveau typeface called?

Tags: font-identification

I recently came across this [chalk art video on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/40684546) and I'm trying to identify a font from it. It looks so familiar and I'm sure I've used it before somewhere, but I can't manage to find it.

It's a rather stylized font so font-ID sites aren't doing me a lemon.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best match would be Art Nouveau Cafe True Type.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: An early version of the font is available for free [on Ttfonts](http://ttfonts.net/font/172_ArtNouveau-Cafe.htm). Thanks a lot for taking the time to dig the font name up.